# Help with shipping charges on Magento

Tags: category, magento-1, shipping

I need help. I want to charge a flat rate shipping charge for items shipped to Canada under a specific category. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this free module for your concern or you can modify the magento core code. However, this is not normally recommended for unless you are a magento expert. 
These are Magento module URL links
*Category and Product Shipping
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-and-product-shipping.html

*Flat Rate Shipping Per Product
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-6.html

Comment: Thanks but I need something that I can set to categories and not products as I have hundreds of products.

Comment: anyone help me -> How can i apply extra shipping charge for only selected products sku? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/238570/57334